# Converting Json response(in String Format) to Json Object

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I am trying to insert some data in mysql which is hosted in cpanel, I have written queries in php files and uploaded in cpanel file manager. I have copied code of php file here which should give me response in json format.

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("sql308.byethost24.com", "username", "password", "b24_18335415_alokdb");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

**Java Code:**

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try{
           JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);//Here my code is failing
            System.out.println("After JSONRESPONSE");
            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
           // boolean success = response.getBoolean("success");
            if(success){
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Registration Failed")
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create()
                        .show();
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
};
    RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name,username,age,password,responseListener);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(registerRequest);
}
```

Comment: try  json_decode($jsonString, true)

Comment: So where is the exact problem? Where you have a problem with parsing?

Comment: Response I am getting is :  <html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("fc4312a20feb8c6a74b0d5342c6cdb98");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+";

Comment: @Robert :  While converting String to JsonObject I am getting type mismatch exception

Comment: What is `RegisterRequest` ?

Comment: The best way IMO is to use GSON lib there you have to create model of json and after that use Gson builder to get json object which later on you can push to your service.

Comment: @xAqweRx  :  its a class with constructor to pass information (name,age,password etc) to volley in Map format. it extends StringRequest so that we get the json response from .php file in String format. do you need to see my code?

Comment: You can't convert the string to Json because your response above is not a Json, maybe there's an error in your code execution on server side. Try send the exactly request with a HTTP helper (Google Chrome has an APP called ARC or use Postman or something) this way, you eliminate the chance of error on Android. To convert the response string in Json, the response might be like `{"sucess":true}`

Comment: Looking now, seems you are returning a Javascript function, there's some in this page ? Maybe a miss formed function is printed on the page, and that's interpreted as a response, the same occurs,  if there's and error or warning in the PHP execution.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions. I created my mysql in 000webhost.com and I am getting the json response in String format. so its working fine now.